# "Adam needs kavod to live" - source

Tags: talmud-gemara, chazal

I've heard the idea that humans need kavod to live being quoted as a maimer chazal from the Gemara but I'm not sure where it comes from, does anyone know of something similar?

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty sure it is a standalone maimer chazal that simply states that people need kavod to survive, so this isn't ringing a bell. Thanks

Comment: Chazal equate embarrassing someone with murder